how do i integrate apache web server in xampp on my new macOS system ? can anyone guide me with a proper steps
I got no results shown for localhost webserver on xampp after installing the application, tried many times to restart the server again and again but still, even after following steps to create a localhost webseerver through terminal and "/etc/conf/" files. !!! and after all of this trying to get through local host its still takes me to the FAQ & Welcome page
tried following the steps of comands :<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/"
ServerName localhost

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apps/wordpress/htdocs"
ServerName wordpress.localhost

and even in the Mac termianl to this : 127.0.0.1 wordpress.localhost
